# Different icon sizes on different devices with the same resolution and dpi

Tags: android, icons, screen-resolution, android-drawable

I'm testing my app on 2 devices - a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Samsung Galaxy Note 2. Both have the same screen resolution and apparently both use the same xhdpi density even though the Note 2 has a considerably lower physical dpi.

My icons on the action bar look smaller on the S3 than on the Note 2. Why is this so, and how can I fix it so that it looks consistent?

---

**Samsung Galaxy S3**

[image: Samsung Galaxy S3]

---

**Samsung Galaxy Note 2**

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 2]

Comment: Do you have screenshot?

Comment: Here's the action bar on the S3 - http://i57.tinypic.com/f0yp7m.jpg
  And here it is on the Note 2 - http://i58.tinypic.com/2lw155u.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even though the resolutions I was using for the individual pixel densities were correct, the actual icon area within the image file had an incorrect size. I followed this guide at iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/ and now things look consistent.